# Homebrew: how to switch between GCC versions `gcc49` and `gcc`?

Tags: homebrew, gcc

I foolishly uninstalled GCC 4.9 after `brew upgrade`ing to GCC 5. However I need both versions and I need to be able to switch back and forth. I thought I could just do `brew switch 4.9.2` but the old version of GCC was installed to the folder `Cellar/gcc49/4.9.2` instead of `Cellar/gcc/4.9.2`, so Homebrew doesn't know where to find the old version.

How can I force Homebrew to install both versions in `Cellar/gcc`?

That is, I have:

```
brew list --versions gcc
# gcc 5.1.0
brew list --versions gcc49
# gcc49 4.9.2_1
```

But I'd like to have:

```
brew list --versions gcc
# gcc 5.1.0 4.9.2_1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t, those are different formulae, and Homebrew doesn’t allow you to install a previous version of a formula.

The workaround is to remove `gcc`, then go back in Homebrew’s history (remember that it’s a Git repository), get the `gcc` formula as it was before the 5.1.0 upgrade, install it, then upgrade `gcc` to get the latest version.

The 5.1.0 `gcc` upgrade was done in Homebrew commit `9cf3d4da1148c0a0d2f42c2fbe75f9a557339bab`:

```
$ cd $(brew --prefix)
$ git show -s 9cf3d4da1148c0a0d2f42c2fbe75f9a557339bab
commit 9cf3d4da1148c0a0d2f42c2fbe75f9a557339bab
Author: David Christenson <david@the-david.com>
Date:   Sat May 2 18:58:17 2015 -0600

    gcc 5.1.0

    Update to latest stable release, add option and patch for JIT, remove CLooG dependency,
    refactor language selection, add HEAD, use HTTPS mirror.
```

You need to checkout the parent commit:

```
$ git checkout 9cf3d4da1148c0a0d2f42c2fbe75f9a557339bab^
```

Then get the `gcc` formula and save it somewhere:

```
$ brew cat gcc > /tmp/gcc.rb
```

If you’re lazy I put [this formula online here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bfontaine/eacd18e2c413005a7526/raw/320a73fc6e1bbf0009a08e6bd90e9d32c3409007/gcc.rb). You can now go *Back to the Future*:

```
$ git checkout master
```

Be sure you removed the current `gcc`:

```
$ brew rm gcc
```

Now install the 4.9 version, either from your local copy:

```
$ brew install /tmp/gcc.rb
```

Or from my online copy:

```
$ brew install https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bfontaine/eacd18e2c413005a7526/raw/320a73fc6e1bbf0009a08e6bd90e9d32c3409007/gcc.rb
```

You should now have a working GCC 4.9 install. Now, upgrade to get the 5.2:

```
$ brew upgrade gcc
```

Done.

```
$ brew ls --versions gcc
gcc 4.9.2_1 5.2.0
```

Comment: Too bad. Is there a way to protect the old version from being removed again?

Comment: Homebrew won’t remove it unless you tell it to. So no, there’s no way to protect it.

Comment: I mean protect it from `brew cleanup`, which is what removed it in the first place.

Comment: I opened an issue for this here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/42039

Answer (score 3):

You can also install both gcc49 and gcc5 from `homebrew/versions`:

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install gcc49 gcc5
```

You can then refer to them explicitly by `gcc-4.9` and `gcc-5` (or by exporting environment variables like `CC`, `CXX` etc)

Comment: I realize now that this is the only way, but I was pretty explicit in my question that I did not want to do it this way.

Comment: I don't see that in your question. You say you need both versions and to be able to switch back and forth, which this allows (albeit not using `brew switch`; you could have a small alias to do so).